# number of rounds xgboost in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

When I perform a grid search using GridSearchCV and xgboost

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=False, random_state=random_state)

model = xgb.XGBClassifier()

grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, scoring="roc_auc",
        n_jobs=4, cv=kfold, verbose=1)
```

what is the number of rounds used internally by GridSearchCV?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by rounds? Do you mean the number of cross validation steps it takes on each run? Or how many different permutations it tries?

Comment: @dataprincess none of the above... it is a parameter of the classifier...it indicates the number of rounds for boosting

Comment: @dataprincess I would like to know what is the setting of this parameter when I run GridSearchCV

Comment: Ah, ```nrounds```. Is that not included in the parameter space over which your grid is searching? By which I mean, is there no way for you to set a range yourself? That's how I assumed it would be controlled.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good answer to this but best strategy is to use high number 500/1000 or even big along with early_stopping_rounds parameter. CV will continue until it will start overfitting on the test fold. Thats when you will get good enough parameters (from bias-variance tradeoff point of view) which you want from CV. In essence though you may be setting too many boosting steps but may be boosting will never happen for that many rounds.

Comment: my question was about the number of rounds used internally by GridSearchCV

Answer (score 0):

Use the `best_estimator_` attribute to find the `n_estimators` parameter:

```
grid_search.best_estimator_
```

Output:

```
XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
             colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, eta=0.1, gamma=0,
             gpu_id=-1, importance_type='gain', interaction_constraints='',
             learning_rate=0.100000001, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=6,
             min_child_weight=1, missing=nan, monotone_constraints='()',
             n_estimators=100, n_jobs=4, num_parallel_tree=1, random_state=0,
             reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=6, scale_pos_weight=1, subsample=0.8,
             tree_method='exact', validate_parameters=1, verbosity=None)
```

You can use this to change the hyper-parameter value in grid search:

```
param_grid = [{'max_depth':[6], 
               'eta': [0.1], 
               'subsample': [0.8], 
               'reg_lambda': [6], 
               'n_estimators': [10,100,1000]}]

xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, param_grid, cv=5, return_train_score=True, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```